# SQL Server Geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, geography

Is there any possible way to improve the below query:

```
DECLARE @radiusInMeters FLOAT = 400;
DECLARE @dgeog geography = geography::Point(given_latitude, given_longitude, 4326).STBuffer(@radiusInMeters);

select [fdx].latitude, [fdx].longitude
from [dbo].[fdx]
where @dgeog.STIntersects(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(20), [fdx].longitude) + ' ' + convert(varchar(20), [fdx].latitude) + ')', 4326)
                         ) = 1
```

Comment: Improve in what way?

Comment: Your qurey don't use any spatial index and your table don't have a geometry column. So query runtime is to be too long.

Comment: My question was somewhat misleading. Sorry for that. My table does have a geography column and a spatial index. However the spatial index was not appearing in the execution plan. Maybe it has to with the way the geography field was created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kcung and Hasan BINBOGA are correct, you need a spatial index.

Look at your query:
  @dgeog.STIntersects(xxxx) = 1
This requires [xxxx] to be a geography data type.  In order for [xxxx] to be a geography data type, the STGeomFromText function must be applied to the row.  And because this is the only part of your WHERE clause, the function must be applied to **all** rows.

If the table fdx is particularly large, this means that the CLR function will have to be applied over and over again.  This is not (in SQL-Server terms) a fast process.

Try this, if you can:

```
ALTER dbo.fdx ADD Point AS (GEOGRAPHY::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)) PERSISTED
GO
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndex_FDX ON dbo.fdx (Point) 
USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID
WITH (
  GRIDS = (LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
  CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 1
)
GO
DECLARE @Latitude DECIMAL(15,10) = 0
DECLARE @Longitude DECIMAL(15,10) = 0
DECLARE @Radius FLOAT = 400
DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326).STBuffer(@Radius)
SELECT * FROM dbo.fdx WHERE Point.STIntersects(@g) = 1
```

A note: You should convert your lat/long pairs into decimals before using them to compute the geography column.  There is an implicit conversion from float to decimal to string when you use a float as an input that will trim your coordinates down to 4 decimal places.  If you explicitly convert first, that will not be an issue.

Also, if you have any null lat/long values in dbo.fdx, you need to filter them in the WHERE clause as a null value will cause your spatial index not to work properly.

Comment: As I mentioned above in my reply to Hasan BINBOGA, the spatial index was appearing in the execution plan. However, I recreated the column using your statement and now the execution plan is different.

Comment: @ancdev A spatial index is associated with a spatial column.  In your query, you never reference a spatial column, rather you use GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText() which computes a spatial value, and a computed value, for obvious reasons, cannot be referenced by your spatial index.

Answer (score 0):

You can create spatial index :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx

Comment: If that's the case then you should use query hinting. Add : with(index(<index name>)) after table name in the "from" clause. You'll be surprise how many times do i need to hint sql server  to use the correct index when doing spatial query.